# Selenium IDE - Trying to store a class attribute a few levels below the id

Tags: automation, selenium-ide

I'm running into an issue with being able to store an attribute using Selenium IDE. I'm trying to store the highlighted attribute, but with the command that I have been using, I'm not able to store the class attribute that far down (highlighted in yellow) and am only able to get the attribute highlighted in blue. [Chrome Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFlMn.png)

Here is the command that I have been using so far along with the result
[Selenium IDE screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJekH.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.